# Unable to split polygon using linestring in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, splitting

I have a polygon that has to be split using a linestring, but I am unable to do that. I tried to split another polygon using this linestring, and it didn't work.

Here are the files:

Polygon I want to be split: https://we.tl/t-PkYQHRQBOr

Line I want to use to split the polygon: https://we.tl/t-rNts4lZXWx

I successfully split the polygon using this line: https://we.tl/t-rmNHl6CRM3

I am using QGIS 3.18.0-Zurich.

Comment: Please add some details about the tools you're using, the CRS your data is in, and a screenshot of polygon and line.

Comment: I am new in this kind of knowledge, I don't even know what CRS is. I just do trial and error using QGIS. It because I just want to make simple geographical project for my work. About the tool, I've told it, QGIS and version I use. Why do you need screenshot? I've included link to the linestring I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I want to use that line to "cut" a polygon. But I never able to do that. I've successuflly split the polygon using another geojson line I make for testing purspose. I will add the file then.

Comment: Again, please add a screenshot of polygon and line - links and uploaded data tend to get faulty, rendering questions useless for other users encountering similar problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer**

Your line is not valid, it contains errors. You can [download here the repaired line](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/LqVcsI4lYLz4lrr) I created with the method described below. You can use it for cutting. The line is in CRS `EPSG:4326` - the same as the line you provided.

**What the problem is and how to solve it**

The problem with the line you provided is that it has several errors like Self contacts and Self intersections

*Self intersection: one of the errors in your line:*
[image]

**How to solve the problem**

If you run `Menu Vector / Check Geometries`, it will notice you about these errors. See here for the documentation of the tool - in fact a core plugin that you have to activate if it is not: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html

You have to repair the line before you can use it properly for cutting. This can be done with Check Geometries and/or manually. You than get a valid line that can be used for cutting.

*Red: repaired line, blue: polygons split by red line with one part of each polygon selected (yellow):*
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! You explained it very well, too.